# Barplot custom x ticks in elegant way

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization

I have this code block that produces a bar plot of grouped stacked bars.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

N=1000
pc_col = [random.randint(1,7) for i in range(N)]
year_col = [random.randint(2020,2027) for i in range(N)]
month_col = [random.randint(1,12) for i in range(N)]
color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'orange', 'magenta']
data = {'PC': pc_col, 'Year': year_col, 'Month': month_col}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n_years = data.Year.nunique()
barwidth=0.7/n_years
for i, yr in enumerate(sorted(data.Year.unique())):
    data.groupby(['Month', 'Year', 'PC']).size().xs(yr, level=1, drop_level=True).unstack().\
    plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', stacked='True', width=barwidth, position=i)
    if i == 0:
        h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.legend(h,l)

plt.show()
```

Of course, if you run this you get plot like this
[image]

If you look closely, you will see that the x tick labels are not in the middle.
So I did some simple math and ended up with this solution to place the x ticks in the middle of the bars

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

N=1000
pc_col = [random.randint(1,7) for i in range(N)]
year_col = [random.randint(2020,2027) for i in range(N)]
month_col = [random.randint(1,12) for i in range(N)]
color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'orange', 'magenta']
data = {'PC': pc_col, 'Year': year_col, 'Month': month_col}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n_years = data.Year.nunique()
barwidth=0.7/n_years
for i, yr in enumerate(sorted(data.Year.unique())):
    data.groupby(['Month', 'Year', 'PC']).size().xs(yr, level=1, drop_level=True).unstack().\
    plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', stacked='True', width=barwidth, position=i)
    if i == 0:
        h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.legend(h,l)
positions = []
for i, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    x0 = i-(n_years-1)*(barwidth)
    x1 = i-(n_years-1)*(barwidth) + n_years*(barwidth)
    middle = (x0+x1)/2
    positions.append(middle)
plt.xticks(positions, [label.get_text() for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()])
plt.show()
```

This solves the problem, however, if someone else, tries to read this, they would probably not understand how these math rules came up.
Is there a more elegant/programming way to do the same job ?

Comment: Change the plot part to this : `plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', stacked='True', width=barwidth, position=i-3) `

Comment: @HMH103 what if the number of bars change? Even if I change the plot to `plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', stacked='True', width=barwidth, position=i-num_bar/2)` what happens if the number of bars is not an even number to cut in half

Comment: The `num_bar` depends on the number of the years you create. In your example let's define `year_start = 2020`  and `year_end = 2027`, then the position is : `position=i-(year_end - year_start)/2+0.5`, which is independent with even or odd number of the bars.